# Upload or Import Excel Sheet with more than one worksheets in Sql Server Table via Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel

I have excel sheet with more than one worksheets and i want to upload/Import this excel sheet into table.
Ex : 
Excel Sheet format : 
sheet 1 
Ram | Kumar | Jain
Radhe | Mohane | Sharma

Sheet 2
Mohan | Kumar | Gupta
Chand | Shekhar | Verma
 i want to upload/Import this excel in sql server table.
table name : info
First Name | Middle Name | Last Name

Answer (score 0):

Link:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-Sheet-into-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net.aspx

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)

    {

        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        string FolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];

        string FilePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath + FileName);

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);

        GetExcelSheets(FilePath, Extension, "Yes");

    }

}
```